# Python: Interpolation from an irregular 2d grid to a regular one

Tags: python, scipy

I'd like to map a distribution of values of an irregular grid on a regular one.
I'm trying with the different interpolators but it looks I'm not able to do it.

Here there is the code I've written:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 100
M = 10

lat   = ((np.random.rand(M,N))*2)+0.2
lon   = ((np.random.rand(M,N))*3)+0.2
theta = ((np.random.rand(M,N))*180)
lat_min = np.min(lat)
lat_max = np.max(lat)
lon_min = np.min(lon)
lon_max = np.max(lon)

dlat = 0.1            # regular step for the lat[rad]
dlon = 0.1           # regular step for the lon[rad]

# Grid dimensions
Nlat = np.int(np.abs(lat_max-lat_min)/dlat)+1
Nlon = np.int(np.abs(lon_max-lon_min)/dlon)+1

# Lat-Lon vector
reg_lat = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, Nlat)  # regularly spaced latitude vector
reg_lon = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, Nlon)  # regularly spaced longitude vector
# Lat-Lon regular Grid
reg_lon_mesh, reg_lat_mesh = np.meshgrid(reg_lon, reg_lat)
```

I've used:

```
theta2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((lon.ravel(), lat.ravel()), theta.ravel(),(reg_lon_mesh, reg_lat_mesh), method='cubic')
```

but the interpolation seems wrong

and

```
f = interpolate.interp2d(lon.ravel(), lat.ravel(), theta,kind='cubic')
```

and it rises the warning: A theoretically impossible results when finding a smoothin spline
    with fp = s. Probably causes: s too small or badly chosen eps.
    (abs(fp-s)/s>0.001)
        kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=36,34 m=1000 fp=14832451.907306 s=0.000000

Comment: What do you mean by "the interpolation seems wrong"?  And also the warning may arise from happenstance location of your random numbers - what happens when you try using linear rather than cubic?

Comment: Better, the interpolation is wrong. If you try to run it it is evident.
The data that I want to interpolate are theta, that are random numbers, so if you do plt.imshow(theta) you will see the different colours that are because they are random values.
If you do plt.imshow(theta2) it is a plane of different progressive values, that do not resamble at all the original data.

Comment: The results from griddata look totally correct to me --- I get a nice bumpy landscape that you'd expect from random data. In particular, I do not see "a plane of different progressive values". Are you sure you plotted the right data?

Comment: The "wrong interpolation" is *not* evident, I also get the bumpy landscape mentioned by @pv.

Comment: Sorry, what did you plotted then?

Comment: I've done something like this:
theta2 = interpolate.griddata((lon.ravel(), lat.ravel()), theta.ravel(),(reg_lon_mesh, reg_lat_mesh), method='cubic')

plt.imshow(theta, aspect = 'auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(theta2, aspect = 'auto')
plt.colorbar()

Comment: This: http://pastebin.com/TUdtY77M The range of values in both plots is similar. imshow(theta) will of course not produce the actual picture of the data since the lat/lon coordinates are random, and the picture is very stretched since M>>N, but there's nothing obvious indicating that the interpolation would somehow be unfaithful.